# Microservice architecture for ETL

Tags: web-services, architecture, etl, microservices, restful-architecture

I am redesigning a small monolith ETL software written in Python. I find a microservice architecture suitable as it will give us the flexibility to use different technologies if needed (Python is not the nicest language for enterprise software in my opinion). So if we had three microservices (call them Extract, Transform, Load), we could use Java for Transform microservice in the future.

The problem is, it is not feasible here to pass the result of a service call in an API response (say HTTP). The output from Extract is going to be gigabytes of data.

One idea is to call Extract and have it store the results in a database (which is really what that module is doing in the monolith, so easy to implement). In this case, the service will return only a yes/no response (was the process successful or not).

I was wondering if there were a better way to approach this. What would be a better architecture? Is what I'm proposing reasonable?

Comment: I am curious why you find micro services suitable for your solution? Apart from flexibility what other non-functional features are you looking for. I would use HTTP only if I cannot use any other faster protocol in my ETL process. Looking at your question, I feel like you are looking for distributed architecture and a ployglot application. Is your current ETL tool a desktop application?

Comment: Is using HTTP mandatory for the architecture to be considered micro service based? I was considering other forms of integration of different components, e.g. Amazon Data Pipeline (basically calls services in a certain order etc)

Answer (score 4):

If your ETL process works on individual records (some parallelize-able units of computation), then there are a lot of options you could go with, here are a few:

**Messaging System-based**

You could base your processing around a messaging system, like [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/). It requires a careful setup and configuration (depending on durability, availability and scalability requirements of your specific use-cases), but may give you a better fit than a relational db.

In this case, the ETL steps would work completely independently, and just consume some topics, produce into some other topics. Those other topics are then picked up by the next step, etc. There would be no direct communication (calls) between the E/T/L steps.

It's a clean and easy to understand solution, with independent components.

**Off-the-shelf processing solutions**

There are a couple of OTS solutions for data processing/computation and transformation: [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/), [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org/), [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/).

Although these solutions would obviously confine you to one particular technology, they may be better than building a similar system from scratch.

**Non-persistent**

If the actual data is streaming/record-based, and it is not required to persist the results between steps, you could just get away with long-polling the HTTP output of the previous step.

You say it is just too much data, but that data doesn't have to go to the database (if it's not required), and could just go to the next step instead. If the data is produced continuously (not everything in one batch), on the same local network, I don't think this would be a problem.

This would be technically very easy to do, very simple to validate and monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to have a look into the Apache flink, It is very similar to what big sized enterprise apps like informatica, talend and data stage mappings but it process in a smaller scale but repetitively. It actually helps you to compute and transform the stuff on the fly/as they arrive and then store/load into a file/db.

The current infra we have with flink process close 28.5GB per every 4 hours and it just works. In the initial days, we had to run our daily batch and the flink stream to ensure both of them are producing consistent results and eventually most of the streams were left active and the daily batches were retired gradually. 
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

There's none preventing you to have an SFTP server containing CSV or database storing the results. You can do whatever make senses. Using messaging to pass gigabytes of data, or streaming through HTTP may or may not make senses for your case.

Comment: Or an object storage such as S3

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. The best solution for this could be **Reactive Spring Boot**. You can have your Extract service to be as a Reactive Spring Boot app and instead of sending GBs of data, stream the data to the required service.

Now you might be wondering that while streaming, it might hold on the working thread. The answer is NO. IT works at the OS level. **It doesn't hold up any request thread to stream the results**. That's the beauty of the Reactive Spring Boot.

Go through this and explore
https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/28/reactive-programming-with-spring-5-0-m1

Comment: Wouldn't that limit me to Java, hence defeating the purpose of using a microservice architecture? We're not even using Java at the moment -- we might use it in the future, or some other technology really. But I'd like the service interfaces to be technology agnostic.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. But let's see what do we have once the feature is released in Spring 5.